# How to use EvtQuery() to get multiple events?

Tags: c, winapi, event-log

I'm following along in the Windows [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/formatting-event-messages), and maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it would appear that all I have to do to iterate through all of the events is to call [`EvtNext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtnext?source=recommendations) until it returns false.

I'm trying to retrieve all events with EventID 5379, which I have a lot of entries for, per this image:

[image: EventID entries a plenty of 5379]

The following C code is what I'm using to attempt to retrieve events with ID 5379 from the Security log. It currently outputs only one event, and then the program ends.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winevt.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wevtapi.lib")
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define TIMEOUT 5000  // 5 second; Set and use in place of INFINITE in EvtNext call

LPWSTR GetMessageString(EVT_HANDLE hMetadata, EVT_HANDLE hEvent, EVT_FORMAT_MESSAGE_FLAGS FormatId);

void main(void)
{
    EVT_HANDLE hProviderMetadata = NULL;
    EVT_HANDLE hResults = NULL;
    EVT_HANDLE hEvent = NULL;
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    DWORD dwReturned = 0;
    LPWSTR pwsMessage = NULL;
    const wchar_t* pwsPath = L"Security";
    const wchar_t* pwsQuery = L"Event/System[EventID=5379]";
    const wchar_t* pwszPublisherName = L"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing";

    // Get the handle to the provider's metadata that contains the message strings.
    hProviderMetadata = EvtOpenPublisherMetadata(NULL, pwszPublisherName, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (NULL == hProviderMetadata)
    {
        wprintf(L"EvtOpenPublisherMetadata failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        // Cleanup
        if (hEvent)
            EvtClose(hEvent);

        if (hResults)
            EvtClose(hResults);

        if (hProviderMetadata)
            EvtClose(hProviderMetadata);
    }

    // Query for an event.
    hResults = EvtQuery(NULL, pwsPath, pwsQuery, 0x1200);
    if (NULL == hResults)
    {
        status = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_EVT_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND == status)
            wprintf(L"Channel %s was not found.\n", pwsPath);
        else
            wprintf(L"EvtQuery failed with %lu.\n", status);

        // Cleanup
        if (hEvent)
            EvtClose(hEvent);

        if (hResults)
            EvtClose(hResults);

        if (hProviderMetadata)
            EvtClose(hProviderMetadata);
    }

    // Get a single event from the result set.
    while (EvtNext(hResults, 1, &hEvent, INFINITE, 0, &dwReturned) != FALSE)
    {

        // Get the various message strings from the event.
        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageEvent);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Event message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageLevel);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Level message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageTask);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Task message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageOpcode);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Opcode message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageKeyword);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            LPWSTR ptemp = pwsMessage;

            wprintf(L"Keyword message string: %s", ptemp);

            while (*(ptemp += wcslen(ptemp) + 1))
                wprintf(L", %s", ptemp);

            wprintf(L"\n\n");
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageChannel);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Channel message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

        pwsMessage = GetMessageString(hProviderMetadata, hEvent, EvtFormatMessageProvider);
        if (pwsMessage)
        {
            wprintf(L"Provider message string: %s\n\n", pwsMessage);
            free(pwsMessage);
            pwsMessage = NULL;
        }

    }

    status = GetLastError();
    if (status == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) 
    {
        wprintf(L"NO MORE ITEMS\n\n");
        status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }

    // Cleanup
    if (hEvent)
        EvtClose(hEvent);

    if (hResults)
        EvtClose(hResults);

    if (hProviderMetadata)
        EvtClose(hProviderMetadata);
}


// Gets the specified message string from the event. If the event does not
// contain the specified message, the function returns NULL.
LPWSTR GetMessageString(EVT_HANDLE hMetadata, EVT_HANDLE hEvent, EVT_FORMAT_MESSAGE_FLAGS FormatId)
{
    LPWSTR pBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD dwBufferUsed = 0;
    DWORD status = 0;

    if (!EvtFormatMessage(hMetadata, hEvent, 0, 0, NULL, FormatId, dwBufferSize, pBuffer, &dwBufferUsed))
    {
        status = GetLastError();
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == status)
        {
            // An event can contain one or more keywords. The function returns keywords
            // as a list of keyword strings. To process the list, you need to know the
            // size of the buffer, so you know when you have read the last string, or you
            // can terminate the list of strings with a second null terminator character 
            // as this example does.
            if ((EvtFormatMessageKeyword == FormatId))
                pBuffer[dwBufferSize - 1] = L'\0';
            else
                dwBufferSize = dwBufferUsed;

            pBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc(dwBufferSize * sizeof(WCHAR));

            if (pBuffer)
            {
                EvtFormatMessage(hMetadata, hEvent, 0, 0, NULL, FormatId, dwBufferSize, pBuffer, &dwBufferUsed);

                // Add the second null terminator character.
                if ((EvtFormatMessageKeyword == FormatId))
                    pBuffer[dwBufferUsed - 1] = L'\0';
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"malloc failed\n");
            }
        }
        else if (ERROR_EVT_MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND == status || ERROR_EVT_MESSAGE_ID_NOT_FOUND == status)
            wprintf(L"!!! -- EvtFormatMessage failed with Message Not Found %u -- !!!\n", status);
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"EvtFormatMessage failed with %u\n", status);
        }
    }

    return pBuffer;
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps it's the `XPATH` which maybe only returns one item? I plan to review that more in depth, just in case.

Comment: You linked to the "Formatting Event Messages" doc, have you read the ["Querying for Events"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/querying-for-events) doc? Also, I notice that: 1) you are not stopping when a fatal error occurs; 2) you are not including the `EvtQueryChannelPath` flag when calling `EvtQuery()` (FYI, don't rely on [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))!); 3) you are not calling `EvtClose()` on *every* `EVT_HANDLE` that `EvtNext()` gives you; 4) you are not logging when `EvtNext()` reports an error other than `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`.

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau. So this is after manipulating the docs example code over several hours. Point 1 and 4 dont really matter as it would return ERROR_NO_MORR_ITEMS while stepping via debugger after 1 cycle.  Point 3 I think also doesn't matter (but even in the original example it used a goto cleanup stub). I'll prob check again but I think I played with adding it. Basically the example code even returns one record. However Point 2 I should def investigate.  Hopefully that's is the missing key but Im fearful if it's not. Cheers

Comment: Are you sure this code actually runs to completion? In GetMessageString() you're accessing a NULL pBuffer before you've allocated it, guaranteeing a crash.

Comment: As far as I know with teh pBuffer this is a copy straight from MS Docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/formatting-event-messages. Wondering if it's something with threads though. I notice when trying to step debug it doesnt find any events. when I run it standalone thru cmd.exe it finds one and then exits. The EvtQuery page says "you must only use the query handle that this function returns on the same thread that created the handle." So will find out how to verify its single threaded

Comment: The sample code there is bad. You need to run as administrator to access this event log, so you need to run Visual Studio as admin in order to successfully debug it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using the [EventsQuery](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/Eventing/EventLogConsumer/CPP/EventsQuery/Events.c#L135) sample with `Security Event/System[EventID=5379]` command arguments. Also with `EvtQuery(NULL, pwsPath, pwsQuery, 0x1200);`

Comment: Hi all. Doing a bit more investigation (even trying to reverse the native wevtutil.exe which failed with hilarity as its been a while since i looked at RE). For @Luke the issue isnt VS Studio needing admin. The issue appears to be in current MSFT sample code the GetMessageString(). Commenting out everything but the first call (Event String) it works as expected.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Your older sample after I casted some types and added the DLL ref worked fine. Alth tho it is XML which Im trying to ouput regular plaintext but still nice a find and resource for when older docs may be simpler/better! The issue in the current sample is something within the GetMessageString function which i havent narrowed down to yet. Thanks to all however

Comment: I've narrowed it down to GetMessageStrong against the EvtFormatMessageKeyword being the problem in my case. Prob won't narrow it down furtherat this time but for anyone else Googling and using MSFT's sample and the same issue it's around there as you see it's a lot different workto generate the string

Comment: Can you answer yourself? There is no problem about [EvtQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtquery) this time but the `Formatting Event Messages` sample.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem in this case the current iteration of the the sample code on Microsoft Docs has an issue with the GetMessageString() function and the data it is recieving from when pulling messages from EvtFormatMessageKeyword. Not able to narrow it down further due to a wonky VS debugger but in this case removing calls to that is a bandaid over the the breakage altho at the loss of Keyword message data